# How can i setup socks proxy for ASIHTTPRequest in xcode ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, asihttprequest, socks

i want to UIWebView transmit all data through socks proxy i already setup proxy url,port,username and password for ASIHTTPRequest but it doesn't work and i dont want to use pac file.

$- (IBAction)Go:(id)sender {

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[TextURL.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

ASIHTTPRequest *request1 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [request1 setProxyHost:@"test.org"];
 [request1 setProxyPort:808];

 [request1 setUsername:@"user"];
 [request1 setPassword:@"password"];

[request1 setDelegate:self];
[request1 startAsynchronous];
[TextURL resignFirstResponder];
```

}

$- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

```
NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    [web1 loadData:responseData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[request url]];
}
```

}

Comment: A bit unrelated to your question but still important info in case you don't know; if this is a new project, you should know that ASIHTTPRequest is no longer maintained by its creator.

Comment: do you know any other way to setup socks proxy for uiwebview?